# Does accidentally putting in a dvd damage a cd player?

Tags: dvd, cd, player

There was a bonus disc with my cd which I assumed to be another cd, writing was very faint. After putting it in realized it was a dvd and now the cd player rarely works, was mostly working before. It’s probably the reason but just wanted to make sure

Comment: No, that wasn't the reason for sure. This is called a *post hoc ergo propter hoc* fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc

Comment: @ChanganAuto I saw your comment and reread her question.  I totally missed the fact she thought that was the reason.  Amending my answer wit some more info.

Comment: No, but doing it **intentionally** will.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no harm in putting a DVD in a a standalone or computer based CD player.  There are many *newer* types of optical media of the same size (like DVDs), but CD reader's lasers and their mechanisms inside are not capable of reading higher density formats.   All that will happen is a failure to read.

I initially didnt notice you thought this was the reason for your CD player failing.  Again, no.  Something else is the cause of it not working properly.  If this *were* true, virtually *every* CD player on the planet would be broken, as at some point everyone purposefully or accidentally put a DVD into a CD player/drive.

Answer (score -3):

No, it will just not be able to read it because the data is recorded in a different way, different sizes and colors on the disk layer.

Comment: Optipical media is called discs.   With a C.  Also, there are no "colors" stored on a disc.

Comment: @Keltari - The nonsensical nature of this answer suggests it’s a OpenGPT generated answer. OpenGPT doesn’t understand context with regards to the colors that represent each layer on a disk.

Comment: @Ramhound I doubt it.  I strongly feel modern AI is smart enough to know that optical media is called discs.

Comment: @Keltari - The probability of it being generated by OpenAI is greater than 75%. I have seen it several times, OpenAI doesn’t understand context, it knows disks have colors so it talks about the colors but failing to understand the reason disks have colors is due to the layers that allow data to be written to it and the color is something we purposely make happen to determine if data has been written to the disk or not.

Comment: I have detected that Ramhound is powered by OpenAI because he just kept calling it disk with a 'k' even after Keltari pointed out that optical discs are spelled with a 'c'. :-)

Comment: @Keltari `colors on the disk layer` well, there are indeed different kinds of dye that has different colors (or "give different shades")

Comment: @TomYan Yes.. true.. but that is what is burned into.  This answer implies color is from writing, which it isnt.

Comment: @Spiff well if he learned something new... SkyNet begins.